# Kubernetes pod recreation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to tell Kubernetes to just throw away my current pod and recreate it again every 48 hours? Is there some type of a scheduler on Google Cloud Kubernetes? Or can I just configure my deployment this way?
I have a Node.js application containerized with Docker running inside of a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What happens after 48 hours?

Comment: first of all, if something happens to your App every 48 hours, then you need to research the reason of problem

Comment: Hey @mbuechmann, hey Konstantin, indeed, sometimes my pod lands to a weird state. Investigation is ongoing, but for now a recreation mechanism will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True "Kubernetes way" to resolve this issue - is to design `ReadinessProbe`/`LivenessProbe` for your app's deployment/statefulset/pod. Once your `Pod` fall down correct probes will handle it and your `Pod` will be recreated fully automatically

P.S: you are the one who knows your app better then anyone. Try out to resolve "every 48h issues" and then make the right probes. Good luck!

Link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

Comment: Thank you @Konstantin! That is actually a really elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CronJobs ?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: your_app_name
            image: your_image
            args:
            - your
            - args
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

It's official Kubernetes docs under [cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).

Also, here is a cron schedule expression editor that might be useful: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru).

Comment: This is just a copy and paste of an official doc. CronJobs only seem to be related, but this will not provide a real solution for the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there are two ways to achieve this. I'm assuming your app is running as a deployment in kubernetes, so deleting pod should create a new one.

1. Exit your node app after 48 hours i.e. exit from within your code, a dirty way, but it's simplest.
2. Create a [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) that runs after 48 hours and delete any pod created under your deployment.

Comment: A cronjob is not quite the best solution. The cronjob runs any task inside a new pod. That pod now has to access the kubernetes master to do a restart of another pod. This should be possible, but now you have to ensure access from a specific pod to the master with all security implications.

Comment: adding permissions is not such a big issue, and if you have Rbac disabled, no need to specify permissions, just issue commands from one pod to other without any errors. I'm already doing it in a project.

Comment: And if you do not have rbac enabled? Mind that these solutions are all a workaround for another problem. While the second solution might work, it adds a lot of overhead to your whole orchestration. Your first solution is much better. The workaround stays where the original problem occurred. It is a software solution for a software problem.

Comment: well yes, that's why I added both the solutions to review.